# How can I get the value of the only field of a field in a json with json.net in a C# class

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like this json :

```
{
  "foo ": {
    "bar": 5
  }
}
```

To be deserialized in this class :

```
class MyClass
{
 int foo;
}
```

Like this :

```
void MyFunction(string _JSON)
{
    string json = _JSON;
    //json == {"foo ": {"bar": 5}}
    MyClass c = JsonConvert.Deserialized<MyClass>(json);
    //c.foo == 5
}
```

Comment: Why not just match the class structure to the JSON structure?

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidG mentioned, match the class structure and you can easily get the value you want. You could go to the point of using this site to help you: https://json2csharp.com
The site will give you the c# class structure of:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>
(myJsonResponse);
```

```
public class Foo
{
    public int bar { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("foo ")]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value from a specific field from `JSON` by `JObject` like this:

```cs
void MyFunction(string _JSON)
{
    JToken jobject =  JObject.Parse(_JSON);
    MyClass c = new MyClass()
    {
        foo = Convert.ToInt32(jobject["foo"]["bar"].ToString())
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Deserialize it into a matching structure:

```
class MyJsonClass
{
    public MyJsonFoo foo { get; set; }
}

class MyJsonFoo
{
    public int bar { get; set; }
}

// and later...
var temp = JsonConvert.Deserialized<MyJsonClass>(json);
```

And then use that object to create your object:

```
var c = new MyClass { foo = temp.foo.bar };
```

Essentially what you have is an external dependency (an incoming JSON structure) which doesn't match your internal domain (`MyClass`).  Abstract that dependency behind a service (class, project, however complex it needs to be) which internally deserializes the result and returns the domain object.  That way `MyJsonClass` and `MyJsonFoo` can be encapsulated within that service and not pollute the domain.  The service is essentially just a translation layer between the two data structures.